# C# Reflection: Typedefinition.IsNested & Typedefinition.IsNestedFamily

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Whats the difference between `IsNested` and `IsNestedFamily` ?
In the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.reflection.metadata.typedefinition?view=net-5.0) of Typedefinition I only see `IsNested`.
But according to InteliSense actually there are both Propertys on it.

[image]

I can only find `IsNestedFamily` in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.type.isnestedfamily?view=net-5.0) for the class Type.

#### So my question:

Can anyone explain to me, the difference between these two Propertys on the Typedefinition class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving on with my search I found this [article](https://www.programmersought.com/article/6494173120/). It seems to be, that `IsNested` generally says, that this Type is nested, and IsNestedFamily describes a nested Type with access modifier `protected`